# UpSetR dataframe as input counts zeros

Tags: r, upsetr

I want to use upSetR to plot some patient's characteristics. each feature is 0 or 1. They are multiplied by an ID to feed the upset function. It counts zeros and consider zero as a patient. I tried to use the following but no luck:

```
    upSetList = list(A = df$col_1 , B = df$col_2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to convert to vectors like this:

```
upSetList = list(A = as.vector(df$col_1) , B = as.vector(df$col_2))
```